# What to use instead of Twig_Loader_String

Tags: symfony, twig

I see that the `Twig_Loader_String` class has been deprecated and will be removed in Twig 2.0. Also, the comments in the source indicate that it should "*NEVER be used*".

There are numerous valid use cases for a string containing a Twig template.

The question is: What to use instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$tplName = uniqid( 'string_template_', true );
$env = clone $this->getTwig();
$env->setCache(false);
$env->setLoader( new \Twig_Loader_Array( [ $tplName => 'Hello, {{ name }}' ] ));
$html = new Response( $env->render( $tplName, [ 'name' => 'Bob' ] ));

echo $html; // Hello, Bob
```

Comment: This does exactly what I originally wanted to do and without the hassle of cache files. Thanks!

Comment: Where does `$twig` come from? Shouldn't this be `$env->setCache(false) ` ?

Comment: You should use $twig->createTemplate (see @Wouter J 's answer)

Comment: Yeah, `createTemplate` is much more safe than cloning the twig service

Answer (score 35):

`Twig_Environment#createTemplate` should be used, as indicated in the [issue deprecating `Twig_Loader_String`](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/pull/1641):

```
// the loader is not important, you can even just
// use the twig service in Symfony here
$twig = new \Twig_Environment(...);

$template = $twig->createTemplate('Hello {{ name }}!');
echo $template->render(['name' => 'Bob']);
```

This code is the most simple way and bypasses the complete caching system. This means that it doesn't have the bad things of `Twig_Loader_String` (it doesn't create a new cache entry each time you call `render`; it doesn't have problems with referencing other templates; etc.), but it still isn't as quick as using `Twig_Loader_Array` (as shown by @AlainTiemblo's answer) or `Twig_Loader_Filesystem`.

Comment: This doesn't actually work. First, Twig_Loader_Array::__construct() requires an array as its only parameter. Second, after fixing that, the render() call throws a Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class __TwigTemplate_dd0d0e2c37a2d0f8b67dcdcd30ecb79029586ee23cd1c76f343d6878b2fdbb35 could not be converted to string error.

Comment: I'm sorry, @AlainTiemblo. Looked way to quick and thought you only removed the blockquote style. I've rolled back your changes again and then replaced them with another code, which works just a little nicer.

Comment: it is also said in the comments of twig_loader_array that it should only be used in unit testing environment and not in production

Answer (score 14):

The `Twig_Loader_Array` loader takes an array of `$templateName => $templateContents` as argument, so some cache stuff can be done using the template name.

So this implementation works:

```
$templates = array('hello' => 'Hello, {{ name }}');
$env = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_Array($templates));
echo $env->render('hello', array('name' => 'Bob'));
```

Or:

```
$env = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_Array(array()));
$template = $env->createTemplate('Hello, {{ name }}');
echo $template->render(array('name' => 'Bob'));
```

To make clear the rumor, **since the very first Twig version, `Twig_Loader_Array` takes an array in its constructor**. All answers initializing `Twig_Loader_Array` without array are wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Try it

```
$template = $this->container->get('twig')->createTemplate('hello {{ name }}');
echo $template->render(array('name' => 'Fabien'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$environment = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_Array(array()));
$template = $environment->createTemplate('{{ template }} {{ replacements }}');

echo $template->render([replacements]);
```

Comment: This will not work, look at `lib/Twig/Loader/Array.php`: `public function __construct(array $templates)`

Comment: Sorry it should be an empty array in the constructor. (or any predefined templates you wish to set.) I have edited my answer.

Comment: Yes this way is ok, but be aware that you don't take advantage of Twig caching system. That's a true answer/workaround to the string loader anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The best is:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/recipes.html#loading-a-template-from-a-string

As example used by me:

```
public function parse($content, $maxLoops = 3, $context = array())
{
    if (strlen($content) < 1) {
        return null;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $maxLoops; $i++) {
        $template = $this->container->get('twig')->createTemplate($content);
        $result = $template->render( $context );

        if ($result == $content) {
            break;
        } else {
            $content = $result;
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This actually seems to work as expected:

```
$tplName = uniqid( 'string_template_', true );
$env = clone $this->getTwig();
$env->setLoader( new \Twig_Loader_Array( [ $tplName => 'Hello, {{ name }}' ] ));
$html = new Response( $env->render( $tplName, [ 'name' => 'Bob' ] ));
$cacheName = $env->getCacheFilename( $tplName );
if( is_file( $cacheName ) )
{
  unlink( $cacheName );
}
echo $html; // Hello, Bob
```

I found the hints here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#using-different-template-sources.

Note that deleting the cache file would not be desirable if the template string came from a database or something similar. I use this functionality for rendering templates that are created dynamically and have very short life spans, usually when debugging and testing.

Comment: \Twig_Loader_array should only be used for unit testing