# Symfony2 call controller-action in twig-extension without service

Tags: symfony, twig-extension

I'm programming a system that has the following functionality: normal users (no programmer or admins) can create content where they can insert "placeholders". These placeholders will be replaced with different content-types (e.g. a hex-color-code, a slider, an image, ...) when a page is rendered. The replacement of the placeholders is a bit complex and has some additional functionality (e.g. define default-values, replace the placeholder with the content in the correct language, ...). Because of this I have created a twig-extension with a "placeholder-filter". This function should get the correct content to replace the placeholder and handle the additional functionality.

Because the content-types are so different there are some - let it call "plugins" - for each content-type that contains the logic for rendering the contents in a controller.

**Now my problem:**

The controller-actions of the plugins return the rendered content. Because I replace the placeholder with the content in the twig extension I need a way to call the controller-action in this twig-extension.

**My thoughts till now:**

I know I can call a controller-action in a template in this way (source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html):

```
{{ render(controller(
        'AppBundle:Article:recentArticles',
        { 'max': 3 }
    )) }}
```

So it seems to be no problem to call a controller-action in twig. But I need this function-call in a twig-extension.

I also know that I can call a controller-action when I implement the controller as a service. But I can't define all the plugin-controllers as services, because the plugins are included dynamically in the system. It would be "hard" to handle also the services dynamically when installing a new plugin (I think I have to edit the service.yml with a script - or am I wrong?). This is why I can't use the controller as a service. - But I'm open to other solutions when you can tell me how to implement services dynamically.

What I've tried already was combining the solutions of these two pages:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html

```
echo $view['actions']->render(
    new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerReference(
        'AppBundle:Article:recentArticles',
        array('max' => 3)
    )
)
```

and https://www.robinvdvleuten.nl/blog/rendering-templates-in-a-twig-extension/

I have now access to the Twig_Environment in my placeholder-filter in my twig-extension but the following code doesn't work:

```
$twig->render( new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerReference(
                            'Extensions'.$namespace.'Bundle:Index:getContent',
                            array('content'=>$contentObject)
                        ), array() );
```

I get the error that ControllerReference couldn't be converted to string (which make sense because ControllerReference is an object...).

**So is there a way to call a controller-action in a twig-extension without defining the controller as a service? Or should I rethink the whole solution?**

Comment: Absolutely rethink the solution. IMO you should make listener, or simple service(s) to parse text and return expected output. Also you should make some kind of cache to store that output instead of parsing it on every request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours "thinking about the problem" i found **a simple answer for the main-question**. When i include the Twig_environment in my filter-function (see https://www.robinvdvleuten.nl/blog/rendering-templates-in-a-twig-extension/) i have access to the twig render()-function. The function works with templates and strings. So the easiest way to call a controller-action in a twig-extension without services is to use the normal twig-template-syntax:

```
// $twig is the Twig_Environment in my filter-function
$myRenderedContent = $twig->render(
    "{{ render(controller( 'Extensions".$namespace."Bundle:Index:getContent', { 'content': content })) }}", 
    array('content'=>$contentObject)
);
```

**Additional thoughts:**

As you can see in http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html calling a controller like this seems to be completely ok in symfony. So i think it is also ok to use this functionality in a twig-extension (because a twig-extension defines additional helper-functions for template-rendering and this is what i want to do with my filter-function to replace special placeholders with special contents).

Maybe it is not the best practice to doesn't include my plugin-controllers as services but i don't see a disadvantage of handling the plugin-controllers like this till now - when you know one: please tell me because i'm open to learn "how to make it better" ;-)

Comment: Note: this solution does not work in every case. Sometimes you have to use Twig_Loader_Array to render the "template-string". See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081910/what-to-use-instead-of-twig-loader-string for more information about rendering strings and caching.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could define a ViewListener and have your controller return the html that you want instead of the Response that's returned by $this->render on a controller.

You would need to use the $this->renderView on the controller and return the result to your extension.

I honestly feel that the whole system set up like this would be very hacky and hard to maintain long term, so I would recommend rethinking it